# Top bar & dock graphical glitches after returning from lock screen

Tags: nvidia, xorg, themes, gnome-shell, 19.10

I have been having intermittent graphical glitches for the past couple of years. Normally they would occur after playing fullscreen games in Steam and I assumed it was something to do with Steam's Overlay and hardware acceleration.

Yesterday, I updated to Ubuntu 19.10 and upgraded my graphics drivers from nvidia-driver-390 to nvidia-driver-435. Now the graphical glitches occur often when I unlock my computer even if Steam hasn't been opened. They also persist until I log out and start a new session.

Here's a screenshot of how the glitches display:

[image: Screenshot of Desktop]

Has anybody seen similar glitches before?